# Do you need a visa for layover in US if you’re a Canadian permanent resident?

Tags: usa, legal, transit-visas, filipino-citizens, canadian-residents

I have a Philippine passport and permanent resident status in Canada. I’m worried because I don’t have a US visa for my layover.

Answer (score 1):

[This US State Department visa wizard](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wizard.html) says that as a Phillipine passport holder, you do indeed need a visa to ener the US for nonimmigrant transit purposes.